# Enum with associated value has retain cycle

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, enums

In order to manage the visual state of my SwiftUI view, I have an `ObservedObject` that contains a `State` enum. Whenever I receive remote data, I use the enum with an associated value so that I can display the content I received:

```swift
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var state: State = .idle

    func doWork() {
        // Change the state to .loading so that we can display a loader in our view
        state = .loading

        let values = doSomeRemoteWork { [weak self] values in
            // work is done, we can display the result
            self?.state = .loaded(values)        
        }
    }

    enum State {
        case idle
        case loading
        case loaded([Value])
        case error(any Error)
    }
}

// Value is just a struct with some basic data inside
struct Value: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let someProperty: String
    let anotherProperty: Double
}
```

```swift
// swiftui view
struct ContentView: some View {
    @ObservedObject private var vm: ViewModel

    init(vm: ViewModel) {
        self.vm = vm
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch vm.state {
        case .idle:
            Button("Get values") {
                vm.doWork()
            } 
        case .loading: Text("loading...")
        case .loaded(let values):
            Text("got \(values.count) values")
                .onTapGesture { refresh() }
        case .error(let error): Text("got an error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private func refresh() {
        vm.doWork()
    }
}
```

This works fine but I implemented a refresh that basically just invokes the `doWork()` method again. When I do so, I can see that the memory usage of my app goes up and never goes down but I can't seem to understand why.

From what I understand, an enum will strong retain its associated values but shouldn't setting the state to `.loading` clear the enum associated value ? Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: What does `doSomeWork()` do?

Comment: It fetches remote data and map it to the `Value` struct @JeremyP

Comment: @JeremyP I edited my example to be closer to what's actually being done

Comment: In your updated code this line `state = .loaded(values)` is implicitly capturing self. You would have to do `self?.state = .loaded(values)` to avoid this. Is this what your actual code is doing?

Comment: @Fogmeister yes good catch, I already do this but forgot to add it to my example

Comment: Hmm... I can't see anything obvious wrong here. What happens if you do the remote work but just print the result without storing them in `state`? Just as a test. Does the memory still go up?

Comment: It's likely that the root cause of the potential memory leak is not the enum, but something else. I'd suggest to profile the app with the Leaks instrument, as well as pause the execution of the app and take a look at the memory graph.

Comment: @Fogmeister good question. If I replace the `.loaded(...)` with juste print statements and refresh, the memory usage stays the same.

Comment: @VadimBelyaev you might be right. I tried to find the root cause with the memory graph. I still have some troubles using the leaks instruments but I'll give it another go for sure